# sugarcrm displaying users list in a multiselect

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am using SugarCRM Professional as well as Community version latest ones.

in Create Projects screen, there is Assign To field which popups all the userslist.
But I want those users list in a multiselect dropdown as I want to select multiple without popup window as per the client requirement.

I dont want to add users name manually in the list, it should be dynamic. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of I would ask why you want to assign multiple users to a project?  Usually projects are assigned to the project manager and individual project tasks are then assigned onto the team members who will complete them.   Is it for reporting purposes?  So the project teams is aware of what is happening? Another reason?

Sugar will only assign one user per record out of the box, in pro you could use teams to represent multiple users assignment, there are also third party plugins that will also allow this functionality to be added to CE.

However if you are wanting more flexibility than static team assignment the you would have to develop something specifically.

Teams a third party module or custom relation ship from users to projects could be used and using hooks/ajax ect a script could be written to populate a multi select on the project with all users.  These could then be multi selected and on save a new team for the project could be dynamically created.

Hope this has helped you.

Comment: Thanks @Andy, The requirement is something from client who says that they cant use teams because of there are so many criteria for individual projects to be assigned. Teams could solve the issue, but client requirement is not enough. Develop custom relation also seems to be difficult, let me try.